# Modern equivalent concrete strength to 'Class Ws 3/4" '

Tags: civil-engineering, concrete, engineering-history

Consider the following extract from a UK reinforced concrete detail drawing dated 1970:

[image]

What is the modern equivalent to this concrete class?

Comment: The drawing probably predates the vast majority of EngineeringSE contributors :-)

Comment: Find the definition for that class and compare to modern standards. You may have to go to technical publications and / or visit a library as it may not be on the web yet unless you are lucky and someone has needed it...

Comment: @NMech It predates me as well. However, there must be a subset of civil engineers who work on the rehabilitation of old structures such as these.